# How create excel and upload in azure

Tags: c#, excel, azure, azure-functions

How could I upload an excel in Azure Function?  I'm using Blob container and Logic App, after execute the code I download and open the file (excel (.xlsx)) in my Azure portal, but I cannot see any data in my excel and I'm getting this error: "Excel cannot open the file 'excel.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the formar of the file".

```
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");


            CloudStorageAccount cStorage = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionStorageAccount"]);

            CloudBlobClient blobClient = cStorage.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ContainerName"]);


            CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("excel.xlsx");




            DataSet ds;
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {



                blob.DownloadToStream(memoryStream);


                IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(memoryStream);


                ds = excelReader.AsDataSet();

                excelReader.Close();

            }


            DataTable dt = CrearDataTable(ds);


            dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
            string nombre = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs().FirstOrDefault(parametros => string.Compare(parametros.Key, "nombre", true) == 0).Value;
            string valor = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs().FirstOrDefault(parametros => string.Compare(parametros.Key, "valor", true) == 0).Value;


            if (nombre != null && valor != null)
            {


                InsertarDatos(dt, nombre, valor);

                string csv = ObtenerCSV(dt);

                byte[] arrayBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csv);

                blob.UploadFromByteArray(arrayBytes, 0, arrayBytes.Length);

                return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, csv);
            }
            else
                return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Bad request");

        }

        private static void InsertarDatos(DataTable dt, string nombreCompleto, string valor)
        {
            // 1. Iteramos por todas las filas hasta encontrar el nombre objetivo
            foreach(DataRow fila in dt.Rows)
            {
                // 2. Transformamos las tres primeras filas que equivalen a nombre, primer apellido y segundo apellido a un nombre completo
                string nombre = fila[0].ToString() + " " + fila[1].ToString() + " " + fila[2].ToString();

                // 3. Si ambos nombres coinciden
                if (nombre.Equals(nombreCompleto))
                {
                    // 4. Añado el valor a la fila
                    fila[4] = valor;
                    // 5. Terminamos con la iteración
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        private static DataTable CrearDataTable(DataSet excelData)
        {

            // 0. DataTable carga los datos en memoria
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            // 1. Añadimos los nombre de las columnas
            dt.Columns.Add("Nombre", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Apellido 1", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Apellido 2", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("DNI / NIE", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Importe", typeof(string));

            // 2. Añadimos a la nueva tabla el contenido de todos los campos.
            excelData
               .Tables[0]
               .AsEnumerable()
               .Skip(1)
               .ToList()
               .ForEach(dr => dt.Rows.Add(dr[0], dr[1], dr[2], dr[3], dr[4]));


            return dt;

        }

        private static string ObtenerCSV(DataTable table)
        {
            // 1. Creamos un StringBuilder para almacenar los resultados
            var result = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                result.Append(table.Columns[i].ColumnName);
                result.Append(i == table.Columns.Count - 1 ? "\n" : ",");
            }

            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    result.Append(row[i].ToString());
                    result.Append(i == table.Columns.Count - 1 ? "\n" : ",");
                }
            }


            return result.ToString();

        }
    }
}
```

I expected a correct excel, but I get this error: "Excel cannot open the file 'excel.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the formar of the file"

Comment: You didn't post any code that creates Excel files. You have some code that creates a CSV file from Excel. A CSV is just a text file. If you store this in a file using the `.xlsx` extension Excel will complain that this is definitely *not* an Excel file. `xlsx` is a zip package containing XML files

Comment: You can create a real `xlsx` file by using a library like EPPlus. Loading a datatable into a sheet is as simple as `sheet.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(dt);`. The resulting Excel file will be *smaller* than the CSV file too.